# How to change SQL format

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, web

I have an SQL Query like this

```php
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `rincian_permintaan` 
    JOIN `permintaan` ON `permintaan`.`id_permintaan` = `rincian_permintaan`.`id_permintaan` 
    JOIN `users` ON `permintaan`.`id_peminta` = `users`.`user_id` 
    JOIN `cabang` ON `cabang`.`id_cabang` = `users`.`id_cabang` 
    JOIN `barang` ON `barang`.`id_barang` = `rincian_permintaan`.`id_barang` 
    JOIN `po` ON `rincian_permintaan`.`id_po` = `po`.`id_po` WHERE `po`.`id_cabang` = '201' AND `users`.`id_cabang` != 201 AND 
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM airwaybill WHERE airwaybill.id_rincian_permintaan = rincian_permintaan.id_rincian_permintaan)
    ORDER BY rincian_permintaan.created_at DESC")->result_array();
```

I want to change the format to:

```php
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tableName');
$this->db->join('...');
$this->db->where('...');
```

And this is what i've tried:

```php
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('rincian_permintaan');
$this->db->join('permintaan', 'permintaan.id_permintaan = rincian_permintaan.id_permintaan');
$this->db->join('users', 'permintaan.id_peminta = users.user_id');
$this->db->join('cabang', 'cabang.id_cabang = users.id_cabang');
$this->db->join('barang', 'barang.id_barang = rincian_permintaan.id_barang');
$this->db->join('po', 'rincian_permintaan.id_po = po.id_po');
$this->db->where('po.id_cabang', '201');
$this->db->where('users.id_cabang != 201');

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('airwaybill');
$this->db->where('NOT EXISTS airwaybill.id_rincian_permintaan = rincian_permintaan.id_rincian_permintaan', '', FALSE);
return $this->db->get('rincian_permintaan')->result_array();
```

Error:

[image: error message]

Comment: if you check first query you have sub query inside NOT EXISTS, where as in CI query builder it is not sub query copy same sub query in where will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to generate sql string for subquery without executing it and use it in the outer query and produce the result.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('airwaybill');
$this->db->where('airwaybill.id_rincian_permintaan = rincian_permintaan.id_rincian_permintaan');
$sub_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('rincian_permintaan');
$this->db->join('permintaan', 'permintaan.id_permintaan = rincian_permintaan.id_permintaan');
$this->db->join('users', 'permintaan.id_peminta = users.user_id');
$this->db->join('cabang', 'cabang.id_cabang = users.id_cabang');
$this->db->join('barang', 'barang.id_barang = rincian_permintaan.id_barang');
$this->db->join('po', 'rincian_permintaan.id_po = po.id_po');
$this->db->where('po.id_cabang', '201');
$this->db->where('users.id_cabang != 201 ');
$this->db->where('NOT EXISTS('.$sub_query.')');

$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```